# Error booting into Odin: Intel Core i9 10900K, XFX Radeon RX6900XT, 64GB G.SKILL ram, Sabrent 1TB SSD, MSI MEG Z490 Godlike

Tags: boot, error

[image]I get this error when booting from my Etcher formatted USB. The ISO checksum was correct.

Comment: I have macOS 11.5.1 running on Opencore 0.7.2 on another Sabrent SSD . I am not dual-booting. Each OS is running on it's own SSD.

Comment: Things I've tried: updated the BIOS; flashed the CMOS; reset the NVRAM; used a different USB. None of these made any difference, I still get the error in the screenshot above.

Comment: I fixed the issue by pressing "e" at the grub screen and changing "quiet splash" to "quiet splash nomodeset". This disables advanced graphics settings until after the boot process is complete. The problem now is the OS doesn't recognize my dual monitor setup. Even under settings->display the one monitor it finds is labeled as unrecognizable and the second monitor is just black.

Comment: Does Odin support the Radeon RX6900XT GPU?